# Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "{"

Tags: reactjs, redux

src/GamesList.js

```
import React from 'react';
import games from './reducers/games';

export default function GamesList({games}) => {
    const emptyMessage = (
        <p>There are no games yet in your collection</p>
    );

    const gamesList=(
        <p>games list</p>
    );
    return (
        <div>
            {games.length === 0 ? emptyMessage : gamesList}

            </div>

    );
}

GamesList.propTypes={
    games: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
}
```

There's a problem with my code...It gives the following error..

> Line 4:44:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "{"
>
> import games from './reducers/games'; 
>    export default function GamesList({games}) => {
>                                                 ^        const emptyMessage = (   6 |
>
> There are no games yet in your
>   collection
>
> );

Comment: how to get it correct?

Comment: I'd recommend a tutorial on basic JS syntax. Look out for how to define basic functions and the differences between them and arrow functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use **arrow** function then it should look like below.

```
import React from 'react';
import games from './reducers/games';

const GamesList = ({games}) => {
    const emptyMessage = (
        <p>There are no games yet in your collection</p>
    );

    const gamesList=(
        <p>games list</p>
    );
    return (
        <div>
            {games.length === 0 ? emptyMessage : gamesList}

            </div>

    );
}

GamesList.propTypes={
    games: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
}

export default GamesList;
```

**OR**

You can use normal `function` like this...

```
export default function GamesList({games}) {
   // ....
   // ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove "=>" in export default function GamesList({games}) => {  } and it should work.

Comment: I tried so but still it doesn't work......TypeError: Cannot read property 'array' of undefined

Comment: in which line you're getting array of undefined? what is the prop value which you're receiving for games? I notice that you've imported games. what is that for?

Comment: src/reducers/games.js                                                                                     
export default function games(state=[],action={}) {
    switch(action.type) {
        default:return state;
    }
}

Comment: It's a reducer why are you passing directly as props to your component. Are you using react-redux?

Answer (score 0):

You mix up two different function declaration syntax.

It should be in function declaration syntax:

```
export default function GamesList({games}) {
    //function body
}
```

or in arrow function syntax:

```
export default const GamesList = ({games}) => {
    //function body
}
```

Note, that the second example (the "arrow function" syntax) the function name is declared as a constant. Both can be used but they can not be mixed in the same declaration.